# c++ change hardware-IDs via WMI

Tags: c++, wmi

Currently I'm working on a program which I would like to fit to a few computers. I query some hardware IDs (disk, mainboard and CPU) with WMI according to this site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx

As SQL is used there, is it possible not only to recieve data via `SELECT` but to change data via a `UPDATE` query? If so, this attempt to create a "copy-protected program" would fail, right?

Comment: No, you can't typically change hardware IDs. (You could always try it yourself, though; just note the original ID, and try to change it via `UPDATE`. If it works, just do another `UPDATE` to restore the original value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WMI` uses the [WQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) language which is only a small subset of the ANSI SQL. The `WQL` language **doesn't supports the UPDATE or INSERT statements**. Also if you want update some property value this depends if the WMI property/class is writable, finally depending of what you want accomplish you must use the [`IWbemClassObject.Put`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391455(v=vs.85).aspx)  or the  [`IWbemServices.PutInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392115(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So how can I find out if lets say my Mainboad-ID is writeable? I don't want to change anything at all, I just would like to find out if it is possible because then my copy-protection would be not useful!

Comment: To determine if a property is writable you must check the [qualifiers of  the property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566365(v=vs.85).aspx)  and check if exists the `write` qualifier.

Comment: as I recently found out it is possible to change to value of e.g. mainboardID. But this is not a permanent change. After commenting the `Put` method and restarting the program, the old ID appears... So it will be interesting, if a programm (which changes the ID) running immediately before my program can circumvent my copy-protection. I'll answer here when I was able to test it.

Comment: after a view tests it seems not possible to change an ID by running a programm directly before my "copy-protected" programm. so this kind of protection might work (at least for some little-talented guys like me)!